# Storing and retrieving microseconds from DA.Time

Tags: daml

I'm working with FIX Timestamp `20180605-03:10:33.0240756` that I need to parse to `DA.Time` to persist as part of Trade information. I also need to get the microseconds back as part of the response message (ACK/NACK).

Ideally I would like to have a simple way of doing it.

Currently I'm only storing up to seconds using the DA.Time time constructor. 
Looking at the https://docs.daml.com/daml/stdlib/base.html#data-prelude-time-24894, seems like the way to retrieve the microseconds is by:

1. creating another time sans microseconds
2. `subTime` both to get the `RelTime`
3. call `microseconds` in `RelTime`

Please advise on whether this is correct, if there is a better way of doing it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under usual circumstances, I would recommend doing the string parsing off-ledger and passing dates and times in as `Date` and `Time` types, but it sounds like you have a requirement to do this on-ledger in DAML.

Your first question concerns parsing a string to a `DA.Time`. There is currently no inbuilt general purpose date/time parsing function so you'll have to build your own. For a fixed format like yours, pattern matching makes that quite straightforward:

```hs
daml 1.2
module ParseTime where

import DA.Assert
import DA.Optional
import DA.Text
import DA.Time
import DA.Date

-- | `parseUTC` takes a string in the format "yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.SSS"
-- and converts it to `Time`, assuming the time is in UTC
-- Time is truncated to whole microseconds.
parseDateTimeUTC utc = datetime yy mon dd h m s `addRelTime` micros
  where
    -- Split out the micro seconds to stay under
    -- pattern match complexity limit
    [dt, ms] = splitOn "." utc
    -- Pattern match on `explode` to check
    -- the format and assign names to characters
    [ y1, y2, y3, y4, mon1, mon2, d1, d2, "-",
      h1, h2, ":", m1, m2, ":", s1, s2
      ] = explode dt
    -- The function will fail on `fromSome` if any of the
    -- integer strings don't parse
    unsafeParse = fromSome . parseInt . implode
    -- Map the parse function over grouped characters and
    -- pattern match the result to give names to the Ints
    [yy, imon, dd, h, m, s, imic] = map unsafeParse
      [[y1, y2, y3, y4], [mon1, mon2], [d1, d2],
      [h1, h2], [m1, m2], [s1, s2], explode $ T.take 6 ms]
    -- Process month and microseconds into `Month` and
    -- `Reltime` types
    mon = toEnum $ imon - 1
    mic = 10 ^ (max 0 (6 - T.length ms)) * imic
    micros = convertMicrosecondsToRelTime mic

t = scenario do
  let t = time (date 2018 Jun 05) 03 10 33 `addRelTime` convertMicrosecondsToRelTime 24075
  parseDateTimeUTC "20180605-03:10:33.0240756" === t
```

To transition between `DA.Time` and microseconds, we need to make a choice on time zone. Assuming UTC, we can define

```hs
epochUTC = datetime 1970 Jan 1 0 0 0
microToTimeUTC n = epoch `addRelTime` convertMicrosecondsToRelTime n
timeToMicroUTC t = convertRelTimeToMicroseconds $ t `subTime` epoch

t2 = scenario do
  microToTimeUTC 1557733583000000 === datetime 2019 May 13 07 46 23
  timeToMicroUTC (datetime 2019 May 13 07 46 23) === 1557733583000000
```

to transition between `DA.Time` and `Int` representations of dates.

If you want the microsecond component of an existing `DA.Time`, you just want the last six digits of the microsecond representation:

```hs
micros t = timeToMicroUTC t % 1000000

t3 = scenario do
  micros (parseDateTimeUTC "20180605-03:10:33.0240756") === 24075
```

Note the truncation to whole microseconds here, that's also mentioned in the description of `parseDateTimeUTC`.